# How to create the Datepicker in textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am search in Google for a long time i need to create the keying type datepicker and also show the popup calander 
[datepicker](http://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/1/eo.web.datepickermembers.aspx) i used this reference but is third party need to install this setup in each system.

I need to flexible to use this code.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1902349.aspx

Comment: @user3129175 if I am not wrong you want date picker with text box showing your selected dat ?

Comment: my textbox should have like this format --/--/---- by default

Answer (score 1):

Try Jquery [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Completely go through the demo and documentation

Answer (score 0):

This will show calendar and when you will select any date will show the date in text box than you can easily access text box value

```
<td style="width: 158px; padding-right: 15px">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Width="120px"          
    meta:resourcekey="txtDate1Resource1"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDate1" runat="server" CssClass="imgbutton"   
   ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" meta:resourcekey="btnDate1Resource1" />
   <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"  PopupButtonID="btnDate1"
   TargetControlID="txtDate1" Enabled="True">
   </cc1:CalendarExtender>
</td>
```